# Incomplete text in xml files causing errors in newly created Android Studio Project

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

Just a minor issue but it's my first time I encountered such error. I'm wondering if anyone encountered the same with the latest Android studio build (3.5.3)?

This is by creating a new android project with blank activity. (checked or unchecked instant apps have the same effect).

Already tried invalidating cache and restart before creating a new project. Still, I get the same incomplete texts and errors. Last resort I have is reinstalling AS.

**Colors.xml**:

[image]

**Other xml files:**:

[image]

[image]

IDE error I encountered (error report which i sent to google):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.createNewEntry(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:94)
at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.visitXmlTag(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:52)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.accept(XmlTagImpl.java:1027)
at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.visitXmlFile(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:45)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl.accept(XmlFileImpl.java:71)
at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlRearranger.parse(XmlRearranger.java:128)
at com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.arrangement.engine.ArrangementEngine$Context.from(ArrangementEngine.java:540)
at com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.arrangement.engine.ArrangementEngine.arrange(ArrangementEngine.java:132)
at com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.arrangement.engine.ArrangementEngine.arrange(ArrangementEngine.java:93)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils.reformatAndRearrange(TemplateUtils.java:346)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils.reformatAndRearrange(TemplateUtils.java:303)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils$1.run(TemplateUtils.java:282)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$runWriteCommandAction$5(WriteCommandAction.java:361)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:263)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1055)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:262)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:319)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:220)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:188)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:321)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:262)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:244)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.run(WriteCommandAction.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:361)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:353)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils.reformatAndRearrange(TemplateUtils.java:272)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.lambda$render$1(Template.java:279)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivity(StartupManagerImpl.java:360)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.lambda$queueSmartModeActivity$3(StartupManagerImpl.java:166)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.lambda$runWhenSmart$0(DumbServiceImpl.java:232)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.lambda$runWhenProjectIsInitialized$6(StartupManagerImpl.java:392)
at com.intellij.ui.GuiUtils.invokeLaterIfNeeded(GuiUtils.java:377)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runWhenProjectIsInitialized(StartupManagerImpl.java:394)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.runWhenSmart(DumbServiceImpl.java:224)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.queueSmartModeActivity(StartupManagerImpl.java:166)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.access$400(StartupManagerImpl.java:48)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$1.lambda$run$0(StartupManagerImpl.java:196)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$1.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:196)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.doRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:380)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.updateFinished(DumbServiceImpl.java:372)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$pollQueueLater$0(TransactionGuardImpl.java:74)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:435)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:419)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:403)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:706)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:375)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't discovered the cause of the error but I suspect some file in the configuration folder is corrupted.

I managed to fix it by renaming/deleting the `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio3.5` folder.

The folder is hidden by default thus make sure you change the settings in **folder option/show hidden folders** first.

Reopen Android Studio, skip importing configurations and it will work again.